# Where do I see the template-path of magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to echo the description / short description of a product in magento.

So my starting point is:

```
<h5><?php echo   $this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()) ?></h5>
```

What echos me the title, but if I edit the getTitle to getDescription it echos me nothing at all. What would I need to do instead of? And where do I get a list of available magento-functions like for short-description, long-description and etc. ?

Comment: Just check what you are getting in option object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Magento models do extends `Varien_Object`.

So in your case do :

```
Zend_Debug::dump($_option->getData());
```

You will get an array like

```
array(2) {
  ["key"] => string(5) "value"
  ["other_key"] => string(11) "other_value"
}
```

From there, it is easy to get what you want exactly : if the key is `key` then do `$_option->getKey()` if the key is `some_key` then do `$_option->getSomeKey()`

As a matter of fact you just have to prepend the key with **get** then remove the underscore and capitalize all "words".

```
array(1) {
  ["this_is_a_really_long_key_with_too_much_words_in_it"] => string(5) "value"
}
// this will be accessed by
$_option->getThisIsAReallyLongKeyWithTooMuchWordsInIt()
```

If you are curious about how it work, I recommend you to open the file `lib/Varien/Object.php` and to get a look at the use they make of the function `__call`

Comment: I would like to add that Varien_Object has great method called `debug()` and it will display its `data` array with checking for recurrence problems. So instead of `Zend_Debug::dump($_option->getData());` you can do `Mage::log($object->debug());` or `var_dump($object->debug())`